# How to download multiple files simultaneously and trigger specific actions for each one done?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I need help with a feature I try to implement, unfortunately I'm not very comfortable with multithreading.

My script download 4 different files from internet, and calls a dedicated function for each one, then saving all.
The problem is that I'm doing it step by step, therefore I have to wait for each download to finish in order to proceed to the next one.

I see what I should do to solve this, but I don't succeed to code it.

Actual Behaviour:

```
url_list = [Url1, Url2, Url3, Url4]
files_list = []

files_list.append(downloadFile(Url1))
handleFile(files_list[-1], type=0)
...
files_list.append(downloadFile(Url4))
handleFile(files_list[-1], type=3)
saveAll(files_list)
```

Needed Behaviour:

```
url_list = [Url1, Url2, Url3, Url4]
files_list = []

for url in url_list:
    callThread(files_list.append(downloadFile(url)),             # function
               handleFile(files_list[url.index], type=url.index) # trigger
    #use a thread for downloading
    #once file is downloaded, it triggers his associated function
#wait for all files to be treated
saveAll(files_list)
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical approach is to put the IO heavy part like fetching data over the internet and data processing into the same function:

```
import random
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import requests


def fetch_and_process_file(url):
    thread_name = threading.currentThread().name

    print(thread_name, "fetch", url)
    data = requests.get(url).text

    # "process" result
    time.sleep(random.random() / 4)  # simulate work
    print(thread_name, "process data from", url)

    result = len(data) ** 2
    return result


threads = 2
urls = ["https://google.com", "https://python.org", "https://pypi.org"]

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads)
with executor:
    results = executor.map(fetch_and_process_file, urls)

print()
print("results:", list(results))
```

outputs:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 fetch https://google.com
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 fetch https://python.org
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 process data from https://google.com
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 fetch https://pypi.org
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 process data from https://pypi.org
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 process data from https://python.org
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be what I need, I'll mark your post as answer once I acheive to implement it correctly.

Comment: I don't find any release of concurrent.features compatible with my python version(2.7), and I can't use 3.x for this function.
Do you have another solution or may it have been backported?

Comment: I successfully implemented it, but I have to warn about asynchronous behaviors.
For example, I initially used to put those files directly in a zipfile, but it's not thread-safe in python 2.7. Then I put them in a list, and compressed them one by one.